# Infinite recursion of function defined with respect to "every $n$"

Tags: functions, cardinals, infinity

I have very little formal mathematical training, so I apologize in advance for what may seem like basic issues in this question's phrasing.

I am trying to determine whether I can make a certain inference from the following biconditionals:

$$
g_1(x) = f(x) 
$$
$$
g_n(x) = f(g_{n-1}(x))
$$
$$
h(x) = g_n(x) \text{ for every n}
$$

In layman's terms, this is an attempt to formally define a scenario where $h(x) \iff f(f(f(f...f(x))))$.

My problem has to do with the wording "for every $n$." Do the above biconditionals permit the following inferences?

$$
h(x) \to f(h(x))
$$

or, more radically:

$$
h(x) \to h(h(h(h...h(x))))
$$

The reason I am having difficulty is that the definition of $h(x)$ is “for every $n$,” so I don’t see how $h()$ can be infinitely recursive. Wouldn't the existence of one more $f()$--and, of course, infinitely more $h(x)$'s--imply that $h(x)$ is not, in fact, "for every $n$"?

Again, I plead ignorance if this is a poorly formulated question. Feel free to edit or comment if I can make my difficulty clearer.

Comment: If $f,g_n,h$ are not predicates but functions (so that their composition make sense), what does $\iff$ mean? (in particular $h(x)\iff\forall n\in\Bbb N\;g_n(x)$)

Comment: You seem to be mixing *functions* and *statements*. When you write "$A\leftrightarrow B$" or similar, this only makes sense if $A$ and $B$ are things that can be true or false, but when you write "$f(f(x))$" or similar you need $f$ to be a function in order for that to parse. Can you give an example of the sort of $f$ you have in mind here?

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is helpful. Would it fix the problem if I replaced the biconditional with an "="? My training is in philospohy, but I am trying to translate a statement like, "I h-know p when I n-know p, for every n."

Comment: More specifically, I am looking at the following statement at the beginning of [this paper](https://philarchive.org/rec/GOLOKM): "you 1-know p when you know p. You
n-know p when you know that you (n − 1)-know p. You omega know p when
you n-know p, for every n." I am trying to determine, based on this definition, whether it's true that you omega-know that you omega-know, if you omega-know.

Comment: please write the statements in logical way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "you 1-know p when you know p. You n-know p when you know that you (n − 1)-know p. You omega know p when you n-know p, for every n." I am trying to determine, based on this definition, whether it's true that you omega-know that you omega-know, if you omega-know.

Your question would have been a lot clearer if you had just said this first!

Anyway, no, this doesn't follow without more assumptions about the "know" operator. If $p$ is a proposition write $K(p)$ for the proposition that one knows $p$, and inductively write $K^n(p)$ for the proposition that one knows that one knows etc. $p$, so write $K^{\omega}(p)$ for the proposition that one $\omega$-knows $p$.

Then your question is whether $K^{\omega}(p)$ implies $K^{\omega}(K^{\omega}(p))$, and this just doesn't follow without more assumptions. The latter is equivalent to $K^n(K^{\omega}(p))$ for all $n$ but assuming only $K^{\omega}(p)$ doesn't even imply $K(K^{\omega}(p))$, again not without more assumptions. In fact we can meaningfully make use of [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) notation here, writing $K^n(K^{\omega}(p))$ as $K^{\omega+n}(p)$ and $K^{\omega}(K^{\omega}(p))$ as $K^{\omega + \omega}(p)$. In general by [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) we can make sense of $K^{\alpha}(p)$ for $\alpha$ an arbitrary ordinal and all of these states of knowledge are distinct without more hypotheses.

Comment: $2\omega=\omega<\omega+\omega=\omega2$.

Comment: Ah, well, that's unfortunate. $\omega 2$ is very ugly notation...